# PHP imap_timeout doesn't work

Tags: php, imap

I am trying to do the following:

```
<?php

imap_timeout(IMAP_WRITETIMEOUT, 1);
$mbox = imap_open("{myuniversityserver:993/imap/ssl}", "qwerty", "qwerty");

print_r($mbox);
```

and when I enter the right credentials it's fast,  but when I enter wrong credentials I must wait for 15 seconds till I get Warning and Notices. Why `imap_timeout` doesn't work? and then how I know that user entered right credentials? will `$mbox` equal `NULL` if he enters wrong credentials?

Comment: have you tested the other types "IMAP_OPENTIMEOUT, IMAP_READTIMEOUT, IMAP_WRITETIMEOUT, or IMAP_CLOSETIMEOUT. "

Comment: no what should I use?

Comment: why not test them all

Answer (score 1):

I should have used `IMAP_READTIMEOUT` instead of `IMAP_WRITETIMEOUT`. Thank you @Dagon .